# type '(dynamic) => Column?' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget' of 'f'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Column where i want to show `DataTable()` with one `DataColumn` where i want to show key data of `header` inside `DataColumn()` and then i want to show key data of `title` inside `DataCell()` and then below that i want to show a `ExpandablePanel()` to show `long_text_type` as header and `description` as collapsed data. I don't want to show `description` inside `DataTable()` because its too long so i want to expand or collapse it with `ExandablePanel()`. After that i want to grab the next map from the list `data` and repeat the proces of showing a `DataTable()` and `ExpandablePanel()` from next map.

This is the list of maps i grab:

```
"data": [
            {
              "header": "FAQ",
              "long_text_type": "description",
              "title": "Service fees",
              "description": "Information about fees and surcharges."

            },
            {
              "header": "FAQ",
              "long_text_type": "description",
              "title": "Returns & Refunds",
              "description": "How to return products and recieve refunds.."

            }

          ]
```

this is the way i grab the json file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestData {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getTestData() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test_json/test_json1.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}
```

And this is the way which i want to use to show `list`:

```
list.map<Widget>((object) {
                    if (object.containsKey("header")) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          DataTable(
                            horizontalMargin: 0,
                            columnSpacing: 75,
                            columns: <DataColumn>[
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  child: Text(
                                    object["header"].toString(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            rows: <DataRow>[
                              DataRow(
                                cells: <DataCell>[
                                  DataCell(Text(
                                    object['title'].toString(),
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          ExpandablePanel(
                              theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                                iconColor: Colors.white,
                                iconPlacement:
                                ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                              ),
                              header: Padding(
                                padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 0),
                                child: Text(
                                  object["long_text_type"].toString(),
                                ),
                              ),
                              collapsed: Container(),
                              expanded: Text(
                                object["description"].toString(),
                                
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  })
```

But i get the following error on `.map<Widget>`:

```
type '(dynamic) => Column?' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget' of 'f'
```

How do i resolve this type error?

**EDIT**

I have edited the error because i forgot to add `return Column` but i still get an error

**Edit**

I have added the function which grabs the json

Answer (score 0):

You have not returned the widget due to this error occurring.
Add return to your widget.

```
                  list[index]['data'].containsKey("header") ? Column(
                    children: [
                      DataTable(
                        horizontalMargin: 0,
                        columnSpacing: 75,
                        columns: <DataColumn>[
                          DataColumn(
                            label: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              child: Text(
                                list[index]['data']["header"].toString(),

                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        rows: <DataRow>[
                          DataRow(
                            cells: <DataCell>[
                              DataCell(Text(list[index]['data']['title'].toString(),
                            )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ExpandablePanel(
                          theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                            iconColor: Colors.white,
                            iconPlacement:
                                ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                          ),
                          header: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              list[index]['data']["long_text_type"].toString(),
                    
                            ),
                          ),
                          collapsed: Container(),
                          expanded: Text(
                            list[index]['data']["description"].toString(),
                            )
                    ],
                  );
                  : 
                 return Container();
```

Comment: instead of `null` i get now  `Column?`

Comment: Then just remove the type Widget form .map<Widget>

Comment: but then i get `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
`

Comment: And if remove `toList()` i get : `type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
`

Comment: Can you please share your full function or widget where you are using this? because I need to know where you are returning this what is the actual type of parent widget.

Comment: I have edited the answer can you do it like this? can you please try ? @StudentOfFlutter

Comment: now i get error : `Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'containsKey'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: containsKey("header")`

Comment: I have edited my question and added the full code

Comment: Then use it like `(list[index]['data'] as Map).containsKey("header")`

Comment: i did but i get the error `Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'containsKey'. Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: containsKey("header")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244127/discussion-between-kishan-busa-and-studentofflutter).

Comment: Future<List<dynamic>> getTestData() async {
String jsonData =
await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test_json/test_json1.json');
  List <dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData)['data'];
return data;
}

Comment: I run your code in IDE, and it works without any warning or error. Check the runtime type of your list variable.
```List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {
      "header": "FAQ",
      "long_text_type": "description",
      "title": "Service fees",
      "description": "Information about fees and surcharges."
    },
    {
      "header": "FAQ",
      "long_text_type": "description",
      "title": "Returns & Refunds",
      "description": "How to return products and recieve refunds.."
    }
  ];```

Comment: But i get error when i use the variable you posted `Error: A value of type 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.` @SuatÖzkaya

Comment: I can not understand at where exactly you are having trouble. Are you sure you can decode your data into a list of Maps? ```List<Map<String,dynamic>>``` This is the first thing you should ensure.

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya what is the code you used which worked?

Comment: Here it is -> I think you are having problem to decode data as a List of Maps. I just created a list of map and you code works. Only removed ExpandableWidget and added toList to the end...
  https://dartpad.dev/?id=e3091cc2c3013d888859b2814a2a5fae

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya the link shows only a flutter demo page

Comment: Try again please I've just linked the gist code now.